# Accessing foreign key values from Redux to map values into card components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I have added include functionality for my foreign keys into my backend API controller and now the values are being pulled into my Redux store where I want them to be.

I am now having trouble accessing the values when I try to map them into card components as nothing is appearing when my component renders. Should they be rendering when I do them like in the screenshots below? I can see from the Redux tree that there is a [0] array number after the foreign key (schoolPhotoID_FK).

At the minute I am trying to access the foreign key state by diveSchoolList.schoolPhotoID_FK1.photos and have tried a few variations but I either get a blank (which I don't think is a CSS/JSS problem) or throwing an undefined error. Does this look like the correct way to access the values? In this example I am trying to access a image URL but it is the same for text values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `schoolPhotoID_FK1` is an array.

Try:

```js
diveSchoolList.schoolPhotoID_FK1[0].photos
```

Comment: Cheers, that's rendering the photos now.

Answer (score 1):

your schoolPhotoID_FK is array or object so if you want to access object at 0 index you can use like follow

```
schoolPhotoID_FK1[0].photos
```